# ¿Cuál es el significado de esta expresión (contador[c - 'a']++;)?

Tags: c

Buenas tengo una pregunta respecto a una cosa que he encontrado ya varias veces en ejercicios de C.

```
contador[c - 'a']++;
c_frec = i+'a';
```

Me cuesta entenderlo, porque `a` es un carácter, y tanto `i` como `c` son enteros (tipo `int`).

No sé como va a realizar las operaciones de suma y resta, con caracteres y enteros.

Comment: Es que los caracteres son valores numericos entre 0 y 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este ejemplo suponemos que `c` es un caracter extraido de alguna parte

```
contador[c - 'a']++;
```

La expresión `c - 'a'` resta el valor del caracter extraido del valor del caracter 'a'. El resultado es un valor entre 0 y 25, que corresponde con la letra del alfabeto: 0->'a', 1->'b', 2->'c', etc.

Ese valor lo usas para indexar un arreglo de contadores y sumar 1 a la letra correspondiente.

Respecto a la segunda expresión

```
c_frec = i+'a';
```

sin saber que contiene `i`, solo cabe conjeturar ...

**Edición**

A fin de ilustrar mejor el punto hare un programa que cuente las ocurrencias de cada letra (minúscula) en un string arbitrario (`alfa`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char alfa[] = "aaabbcccefg";
    int contadores[26] = {0};
    
    for (int i = 0; alfa[i]; i++) {
        int c = alfa[i];
        contadores[c - 'a']++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (contadores[i]) {            
            printf("%c = %d\n", i + 'a', contadores[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

produce:

```
a = 3
b = 2
c = 3
e = 1
f = 1
g = 1
```

Comment: Esto es falso, el carácter  'a' no equivale a 0, y lo demás no va en ese orden. El valor de los caracteres depende de la tabla ASCII. 'a' vale 97, el resultado sería el valor númerico de c menos 97.

Comment: @Gabitohh. The C Programming Language, K&R, 2° Edition, Section 2.7, *Type Conversions*. Edite mi pregunta para incluir tus observaciones.

Comment: En tu programa imprimes i (que puede ser del 0 al 26), sumado el valor de a. Lo que termina siendo mayor de 128, por lo que vuelve a los valores negativos de la tabla, para un entero sin marca va imprimir lo que dices. Prueba con la cadena "+*&".

Comment: Por cierto el C de K&R ya no se usa, la mayoría de compiladores usan ANSI C, los mas modernos siguen el estándar ISO. La pregunta tiene la etiqueta C, por lo tanto se refiere al estándar actual.

Comment: Puedes ver este ejemplo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/DjosrM69EITcxM0@jLD8zRVOhmksBCJIzEosUkhVsFdQT1a1BImDRgiKg4jQNJdWUmDwlnWRNa67a//8B "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Gabitohh: Revisemos la expresión `i + 'a'`. El último valor en el `for` es `i = 25`, sumado con 'a' (vale 97) da 122. Revisando la tabla ASCII, 'z' vale 122. Todo calza.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero en tu respuesta dices que a cualquier número entero que se le reste el valor de a, va a dar un valor entre 0 y 25. No se sabe que valor tiene c, y por lo tanto es imposible saber si es una letra del alfabeto (en la tabla ASCII) , por lo mismo te pregunto crees que pasaría lo mismo con un carácter como $ o &?

Comment: @Gabitohh. Es bien obvio que esa expresión se ocupa en el contexto de contar letras minúsculas. Es un patrón familiar en C. Si quieres contar cualquier carácter, simplemente usas `contador[c]++`, con `int contador[128] = {0};`. Y si es por hilar fino, `c - 'a'` falla con `c = INT_MIN`.

Comment: En otras palabras, adivinaste. No entiendo como puedes estar tan seguro del valor de una variable, sin ver su inicialización. Tu respuesta se basa en una suposición, solo aplica cuando se trata con letras del alfabeto. Por lo mismo digo que lo que dices  *"El resultado es un valor entre 0 y 25, que corresponde con la letra del alfabeto: 0->'a', 1->'b', 2->'c', etc."* es falso.

Comment: @Gabitohh. Años de experiencia.

Answer (score 1):

Un caracter tiene un código numérico al que es equivalente. Por ejemplo el código del caracter `'a'` según la [tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) es 97. De forma simple  en C se pueden usar los caracteres como si fueran enteros, por ejemplo:

```
int a = 2 + 'a'; // es equivalente a int a = 2 + 97
char b = 64; // es equivalente a char b = '@'
int c = 'a' + 'b'; //es equivalente a int c = 97 + 98;
```

Answer (score 1):

> No sé como va a realizar las operaciones de suma y resta con caracteres y enteros.

Los *"carácteres"* también son enteros, lo que pasa es que solo tienen capacidad de 8 bits. Es decir que solo pueden almacenar números del 0 al 255, lo que es equivalente a 2 elevado a la 8. El valor de cada carácter esta en la tabla ASCII, que se puede consultar en Internet fácilmente o con el comando `man ascii` (si estás es Linux).

### ¿Cómo es posible que un entero imprima letras?

Esto es posible al formato `char` `"%c"`, este lo que hace es convertir el valor numérico del número entero en la tabla ASCII, para que de esta manera visualizar un carácter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef short int caracter;

int main(void) {
    caracter c = 97;

    printf("%c\n",c);
}
```

Este pequeño programa va a imprimir la letra "a", debido a que se usa el formato `"%c"` para que el valor de 97 se convierta en el carácter que representa en tabla. Ahora, el formato `"%s"` es otra cosa, este espera imprimir literales de cadena o arrays de tipo `char` únicamente. Sin embargo, si quisieras podrías imprimir un *"string"*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    short int s[] = {97,98,99,0};
 
    for (int i = 0;s[i] != 0;i++)
        printf("%c",s[i]);
 
    puts("");
}
```

*Esto imprimiría "abc"*

No es buena idea usar arrays de enteros para representar cadenas de caracteres, debido a que no puedes asignarles literales de cadena y tampoco usar el formato de un string. También puedes asignarle carácteres a enteros de mayor talla, tipo `int c = 'a';`. Sin embargo, esto es innecesario ya que los valores mayores a 255 reiniciarían la cuenta: `256 => 0, 257 => 1, ...`

### ¿Cómo es posible que se hagan operaciones arítmeticas con carácteres y números enteros?

En el ejemplo que pones se le resta el valor númerico de 'a' a `c` para acceder al indice de contador e incrementarle en 1. Luego a `c_frec` se le asigna el resultado de la suma de `i` más el valor númerico de 'a'.

Todo esto es posible al [casting implícito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversi%C3%B3n_de_tipos), el compilador va a ser todo lo posible para evaluar el valor númerico del carácter, sin necesidad que hacer un casting explícito.

```
(int)'a'
```

Esto se llama promoción y no solo pasa con carácteres y enteros si no que también con otros tipos de datos, por ejemplo flotantes y enteros.

```
float f = 3.14 + 1;
```

De esta manera es posible hacer una resta entre un entero y un carácter.